# How to add rows to data frame with NA's in some columns

Tags: r

I have a data set of ecological survey data. My full data set has 9 transects. 5 quadrats were placed randomly along the length of each transect, and all individuals present within each quadrat were counted. Here is a subset of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(Quadrat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Transect = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), Species = c("CUNN", "CUNN", "DOL", "DOL", "FLOU", "FLOU", "DOL", "DOL", "CUNN", "DOL", "DOL", "DOL", "DOL", "DOL", "DOL")), row.names = c(98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 786L, 787L, 788L, 789L, 790L, 998L, 1227L, 1228L, 1229L, 1230L, 1231L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, this data set is missing values for quadrat 2- this is because there were no individuals present in this quadrat, and therefore nothing was recorded.

I am looking to add a row for quadrat 2 in which the values for quadrat and transect are filled, but the species value says "NA". This is part of a larger data set, so ideally I do not have to manually fill in the transect and quadrat number each time. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your factor data in *Quadrat* with all level info

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(as.numeric(levels(df$Quadrat)), function(x) 
  rbind(ifelse(!any(x == df$Quadrat), 
          list(c(x, 4, NA)), list(df[df$Quadrat == x,])))))
     Quadrat Transect Species
98         1        4    CUNN
99         1        4    CUNN
100        1        4     DOL
101        1        4     DOL
5          2        4    <NA>
786        3        4    FLOU
787        3        4    FLOU
788        3        4     DOL
789        3        4     DOL
790        3        4    CUNN
998        4        4     DOL
1227       5        4     DOL
1228       5        4     DOL
1229       5        4     DOL
1230       5        4     DOL
1231       5        4     DOL
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `add_row`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  add_row(Quadrat = "2", Transect = "4", Species = NA) %>% 
  arrange(Quadrat)
```

```
  Quadrat Transect Species
1        1        4    CUNN
2        1        4    CUNN
3        1        4     DOL
4        1        4     DOL
5        2        4    <NA>
6        3        4    FLOU
7        3        4    FLOU
8        3        4     DOL
9        3        4     DOL
10       3        4    CUNN
11       4        4     DOL
12       5        4     DOL
13       5        4     DOL
14       5        4     DOL
15       5        4     DOL
16       5        4     DOL
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could append a row and re-order:

```
df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c(2, 4, NA)
df <- df[order(df$Quadrat),]
```

Output

```
     Quadrat Transect Species
98         1        4    CUNN
99         1        4    CUNN
100        1        4     DOL
101        1        4     DOL
16         2        4    <NA>
786        3        4    FLOU
787        3        4    FLOU
788        3        4     DOL
........
```